# Need help with Opus Make!

Tags: makefile

I've received a code that uses Opus Make as a build utility.  I've gone to http://www.opussoftware.com and found Opus Make has been around for a while, but it's not clear to me whether the tool is still supported.  Does anyone know much about Opus Make?  Is it still supported?  Can I use it under Windows XP?  I've sent a request to the vendor of the tool, but have yet to receive a reply.  I'm wondering if I'll need to rewrite the makefile...

Answer (score 0):

There's a tutorial online at http://www.opussoftware.com/tutorial/tutorial.htm that suggests that the core is orthodox `make` with some unique extensions.  Whether you're going to have to rewrite your makefile depends on what is in it.  The web pages have interesting (read 'old') dates on them; and the platforms available read from ante-diluvian times (DOS, OS/2, Win95, WinNT).

The web-site is still up; they probably will sell you the software.  There's a moderate chance the NT version will run on XP.

On the whole, though, the impression given is of benign neglect.  I would decide which other variant of make I was using and modify the makefile to work with that.

Answer (score 0):

The Win95 version of Opus Make will run under Windows XP. It will also run under the Windows 7 32 bit version, but it will not run under Windows 7 64. I'm not sure about the WinNT version of Opus Make.